# how to save custom data into header in movie file using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, headers, attributes

I was looking for saving custom data into movie file using ffmpeg mainly actual start frame, end frame, and other few information something like key:value pair, so later on I can fetch the details from movie file on the go.

I looked all over but couldn't figure out myself. Is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't mention which container format you want this facility for, since some don't allow custom tags.

FFmpeg's Matroska muxer allows random tags, so

```
ffmpeg -i input -c copy
       -metadata key1=value1
       -metadata:s:v key2=value2
       -metadata:s:a:0 key3=value3
out.mkv
```

The first metadata options set a global value, the 2nd is applied to all video streams, and the third to the 1st audio stream only.

Mediainfo and ffprobe can show these values.

Comment: Thanks @Mulvya, it worked like charm!! I have to push some data into .mov, .qt files for now, and looks like as you mentioned, its not adding any data into .mov files, I can clearly see my custom data in .mkv file though, is there any way to add this into .mov or .qt files?

Comment: Can we add multiple metadata tag (-metadata:s:v key2=value2) for video like how can I pass coma separated or I need to write multiple commands for same, is there any way to do this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54248390/add-multiple-metadata-in-video-using-ffmpeg-command

Answer (score 1):

got it.. after doing some digging on same line -metadata found this amazing post - https://jmesb.com/how_to/create_id3_tags_using_ffmpeg this will do any format I believe.

ffmpeg supports few tags which can be manipulated like title, comments, artists, album, track

```
ffmpeg32 -i out.mov-metadata publisher="Publishers Info" -metadata artist="my metadata" -metadata album="another data" -metadata TIT3="more data" out2.mov
```

this way I could able to add custom data into metadata, though TIT3 is for subtitles, we at work never use it, so I could able to hack through this attribute.

Comment: Please include at least a *summary* of that content here. Posts which contain [merely a link and nothing else](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/147191) are likely to be deleted.

Comment: That's only for MP3s or for formats that support ID3 tags.

Comment: it supports .mov as well, I think by using existing attribute I could able to save custom data for formats like .mov and .qt