# How Can I Edit a Video File's "Comments" Field?

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata

If you open a Video File using VLC,
and then press Ctrl-I (Media Information),
you can then see a **"Comments"** textbox on the bottom,
and some more textboes for other fields.

Can FFMPEG Edit these fields, without re-encoding the video?

Specifically I would like to Edit the Comments field.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`-metadata`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options) option:

```bash
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy -metadata title="Your Title" -metadata artist="spaceman" -metadata comment="Comments go here" output.mp4
```

- `-c copy` enables [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) mode so there will be no re-encoding.
- See [MP4 metadata tag list](https://superuser.com/a/1208277).

Comment: Works great, thank you very much, also for the full -metadata Tag List

Comment: BTW, If I Edit the "Comments" field, and want to do it on the same original file, without outputting a second Output file, and without rewriting the whole original file (which might be several GBs in size), is there maybe a way to do it?

Comment: @spaceman Not with ffmpeg. It is not able to perform in-place file editing, meaning you have to make a new output.

Comment: I understand. Is there another program that you might know, that can do it in-place?

Comment: @spaceman I'm not sure. It's not something I do often. You can ask at [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

This can also be done with [exiftool](https://exiftool.org/) for MP4/Mov videos (not for mkvs).  The command would be

```bash
exiftool -Comment="New Comment" file.mp4
```

This command creates backup files.  Add [`-overwrite_original`](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#overwrite_original) to suppress the creation of backup files.  Add [`-r`](https://ExifTool.org/exiftool_pod.html#r-.--recurse) to recurse into subdirectories.

Exiftool only edits metadata and cannot alter the video's streams.

Comment: Thank you very much StarGeek, it's great to also have an option when we just need to edit the field, without editing the video itself.. I will use both (FFMPEG and ExifTool) options, depending on the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Apparantly there's also an easy way using VLC itself.
When pressing Ctrl-I, and arriving at the Media Information window,
this window enables you to also Edit the fields it shows, and not just View them.

So for anyone who needs a quick Edit, for just one file, this option is good too.